# Capillary action in the presence of pin holes

Tags: capillary-action

Assume that capillary forces are sufficient to draw a fluid up a tube.  Now repeat the experiment with very tiny pin-holes in the tube.  The question:  do the pin-holes limit the capillary action?  Or do the capillary forces allow the fluid to span the pin-holes and continue to be drawn up the tube?

Answer (score 1):

I think it depends on the size of the holes, if they are smaller pin holes then it will not stop it, as the water will simply span the hole due to surface tension and cohesion. If the holes are bigger, the water will not as closely adhere to the main tube, this would effectively end the tube, as water would not travel further up the tube due to a lack of enough to adhere to.

Comment: +1 When pin holes are big enough that water can flow out of them then we could create perpetual motion machine by using a turbine to get work out of the water flowing out and falling down.